# How can i code for get required details from DB using SQL code

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am new for SQL, I need to get details from db like,

1. id, sku, name, status
2. sku,name,category
3. sku, category

Mentioned above my example requirement. How can i code for get details from database?

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT 
>       `e`.`sku`, 
>       IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`,
>       IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description`
>
> FROM     `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
>       INNER JOIN 
>            `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` 
>                  ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
>                     (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON
>   ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` =
>   'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
>                     `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 
>       LEFT JOIN 
>             `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` 
>                  ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
>                     (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON
>   ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` =
>   'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
>                     (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) 
>       INNER JOIN 
>            `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` 
>                  ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
>                     (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON
>   ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` =
>   'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
>                     `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 
>       LEFT JOIN 
>             `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` 
>                  ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
>                     (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON
>   ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` =
>   'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
>                     (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1)

Comment: how can i display category_name

Answer (score 0):

**Direct sql query for Magento**

```
/**
 * Get the resource model
 */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/**
 * Retrieve the read connection
 */
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('your-table-name');
//take a look at your config.xml that added your-table-name table for the correct name   
/**
 * Execute the query and store the results in $results
 */
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

// display result

foreach($results as $row){
   echo $row['fieldName']
}
```

the categories names are in the table **catalog_category_entity_varchar**

```
select cat.*, cv.value as `category_name` from `catalog_category_entity` as cat
    join `catalog_category_entity_varchar` as cv on cat.entity_id = cv.`entity_id`
    join `eav_attribute` as att on att.`attribute_id` = cv.`attribute_id`
    join `eav_entity_type` as aty on att.`entity_type_id` = aty.`entity_type_id`
    where aty.`entity_model` = 'catalog/category' and att.`attribute_code` = 'name' and cv.`store_id` = 0
```

for default store i Used value 0 (store_id = 0). if you have multiple store check in **core_store** table

Comment: how can i get sku and image path using sql